# Confused about Android Room call from main thread

Tags: android, android-room, android-viewmodel, android-mvvm

I'm looking at tutorials online for Android Room with ViewModel and LiveData, and I see this done always:

```
WordRepository(Application application) {
    WordRoomDatabase db = WordRoomDatabase.getDatabase(application);
    mWordDao = db.wordDao();
    mAllWords = mWordDao.getAllWords();
}
```

The getAll() method (SELECT * FROM whatever) is called in the constructor of the repository. Isn't this a call for a DAO method from the main thread? All other DAO calls are called explicitly on background threads but always in the constructor it's just called normally? Why is it done like this?

Quote from a tutorial without explanation:

"With the exception of the getAllProducts() DAO method (which returns a LiveData object) these database operations will need to be performed on separate threads from the main thread using the AsyncTask class."

Why is getAll() an exception?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, your question about [Android Room with a View - Java](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view?hl=en&continue=https%3A%2F%2Fcodelabs.developers.google.com%2F%3Fcat%3Dandroid#8).
It's safe to call this method on the main thread because this method only creates `LiveData` object and starts data request on the background. When data will be loaded, then it'll be posted to the main thread by method `postValue()`. It's safe to call this method from the worker thread.